# Quadratic subfield of cyclotomic field

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, cyclic-groups, roots-of-unity

Let $p$ be prime and let $\zeta_p$ be a primitive $p$th root of unity. Consider the quadratic subfield of $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_p)$. For instance, for $p=5$ we get the quadratic subfield to be $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt5)$ obtained by the relation between the golden ratio and $\cos(2\pi/5)$ (the minimal polynomial of the golden ratio $\phi$ is $x^2-x-1$ and so the extension is quadratic).

Also $\cos(\pi/5)=\phi/2\implies \cos(2\pi/5)=\phi^2/2-1$ by double angle identity.

> Is it true that in general the quadratic extension is $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{\pm p})$ where $\pm$ depends on whether $p$ is $1$ or $-1$ $\pmod 4$?

Please prove or disprove.

Comment: Dear user, I think that the $\sqrt{\pm 5}$ in your second last line should be a $\sqrt{\pm p}$. Also, the answer to your question is "yes, it is true".  This is a very standard result, that you can find in many texts, e.g. Ireland and Rosen.  Why do you want additional proofs?  And at what level do you want them?  (E.g. do you know enough algebraic number theory to follow a proof via discriminant calculations?)  Regards,

Comment: Thanks for catch it; yes I mean p instead of 5. :)

Comment: My instructor for abstract algebra (Galois theory) briefly talked about this but he never gave a proof. I don't know if I have enough knowledge of algebraic number theory, but we did go over discriminant of polynomials during the course. Thank you.

Comment: As a side: you might want to exclude the case $p=2$. Regards.

Answer (score 13):

Here is another approach, of a more algebraic number-theoretic nature.

A basic fact is that any finite extension $K$ of $\mathbb Q$ has an invariant
attached to it, a number, called its discriminant.  As the name suggests, 
it is related to discriminants of polynomials.

It is defined as follows: if $\alpha \in K$, we say $\alpha$ is an *algebraic integer* of $K$ if the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ (i.e. the unique irreducible monic polynomial in $\mathbb Q(x)$ that has $\alpha$ as a root) has integer coefficients.  (So e.g. $i$ is an algebraic integer in $\mathbb Q(i)$, but $i/2$ isn't.  Algebraic integers are to $K$ as usual integers are to $\mathbb Q$.)

If $\alpha \in K$ is an algebraic integer, then the discriminant of its minimal polynomial is an integer, which we refer to as the discriminant of $\alpha$.  We define the discriminant of $K$ to be the g.c.d of
the discriminants of the $\alpha$, where $\alpha$ runs over all algebraic integers for which $K = \mathbb Q(\alpha)$.  (If one wants to be subtle, one
can include a sign in the discriminant, but I won't worry about that here,
so everywhere that I talk about the discriminant of a polynomial, I should really
be talking about its absolute value.)

E.g. if $\zeta_p$ is a $p$th root of $1$, so that $L := \mathbb Q(\zeta_p)$ is the $p$th cyclotomic field, then it turns out that the discriminant of $L$ is actually equal to the discriminant of $\zeta_p$, which is equal to $p^{p-2}$.

E.g. the discriminants of quadratic extensions of $\mathbb Q$ are easy to compute, and if $p$ is an odd prime, then there is a unique quadratic field
whose discriminant is divisible by no prime but $p$, namely $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{\pm p})$, where the sign is chosen so that $\pm p \equiv 1 \bmod 4$.  (And in fact
the discriminant is then exactly equal to $p$.)

One property of discriminants is that if $K$ is a subfield of $L$,
then the discriminant of $L$ is divisible by the discriminant of $K$ raised to
the power of the degree $[L:K].$

Combining this fact with the preceding two examples, we see that if
$K$ is a quadratic subfield of $\mathbb Q(\zeta_p)$, then its discriminant is divisible by
only prime, namely $p$, and  this uniquely determines $K$ to be $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{\pm p})$ (where $\pm p \equiv 1 \bmod 4$).

[If you know no algebraic number theory, this will seem like hocus-pocus; but 
in fact it doesn't take more than the most basic algebraic number theory to fill in all the details.]

Comment: And we can also say that the conductors of both the quadratic subfield in question and the cyclotomic field are the same, hence the containment. It then depends upon the knowledge of OP to justify these claims. In any case, thanks for the good answer.

Comment: @awllower: Dear awllower, Yes, but the theory of conductors for abelian extensions really only makes sense once you have CFT, whereas the theory of discriminants is elementary algebra, e.g. much easier than the fact that rings of algebraic integers are Dedekind domains, or the Galois theory of algebraic number fields (including ramification theory), not to mention finiteness of the class group or the unit theorem. It just involves the most basic facts about algebraic integers and determinants.  This is why I posted this answer: because it is not the standard one, and uses much less ...

Comment: ... than one might imagine.  Regards,

Comment: Good! I forgot that the theory of discriminants is so very elementary. I oft thought of it as difficult and arithmetical because of my poor understanding. Sorry for the misunderstanding caused by te foregoing comment. Regards.

Comment: @awllower: Dear awllower, There's no need to apologize!  Best wishes,

Comment: Why do you choose the sign so that $\pm p \equiv 1 \bmod 4$?

Answer (score 4):

**Hint.** The quadratic Gauss sum $S=\sum_{i-1}^{p-1}\left(\frac{i}{p}\right)\zeta_p^i$ satisfies $S^2=\left(\frac{-1}{p}\right)p$, where $\left(\frac{a}{p}\right)$ is the Legendre symbol.

Answer (score 4):

> Below is a not-so-arithmetic proof. It can be found, for example, in [this 
>   **Outline**  article](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~r-ash/Ant/AntApp.pdf), and is **not** my original idea.

First determine explicitly the galois group of the $p$-th cyclotomic field. Then find its unique subgroup of index $2$.Hence compute the fixed field of that subgroup. You shall end up with the quadratic gauss sum as in the answer by *Warren Moore*. So the task is now reduced to showing the proposed equality. Now let the notations be as in the answer by *Moore*.

> Then we evaluate the gauss sum. Write
>   $$S^2=\sum_{i=1}^{p-1}\sum_{j=1}^{p-1}\left(\dfrac{ij}{p}\right)\zeta_p^{i+j}=\sum_i\sum_{j\equiv ik\pmod p}\left(\dfrac{i^2k}{p}\right)\zeta_p^{i+ik}$$
>   $$=\sum_i\sum_k\left(\dfrac{k}{p}\right)\zeta_p^{i(1+k)}=\sum_{k=1}^{p-1}\left(\dfrac{k}{p}\right)\sum_i\zeta_p^{i(1+k)}$$.

When $p\not\mid(1+k)$, the latter sum is -1; else the sum is $p-1$. So the gauss sum turns out to be

$$-\sum_{k=1}^{p-2}\left(\dfrac{k}{p}\right)+\left(\dfrac{-1}{p}\right)(p-1)=-\sum_{i=1}^{p-1}\left(\dfrac{k}{p}\right)+\left(\dfrac{-1}{p}\right)p$$.

As a last step, show that the final sum becomes the desired result.

In addition, one could avail, either of the theory of ramifications, in algebraic number theory, or of the class field theory, to give different proofs. But I suppose that they are not so appropriate to your question, right?
In any case, hope you enjoy the proof.
Inform me of any errors, thanks in advance.

Comment: Of course some amount of arithmetics is involved, but, compared with class-field theory, or with ramifications, this appears to be quite algebraic. Regards.

Comment: How does this fit in with theory of Gaussian periods? If $g$ is a primitive root of $p$ and we set $z_{k} =\zeta_{p} ^{g^{k}}$ then the sum $S$ of your post should be equal to $$(z_{0}+z_{2}+z_{4}+\cdots +z_{p-3})-(z_{1}+z_{3}+\cdots +z_{p-2})$$ Both the expressions in parentheses above are Gaussian periods of $(p-1)/2$ terms and are the roots of a quadratic equation with rational coefficients and $S^{2}$ is the discriminant of this equation which turns out to $\pm p$.

Comment: Sorry to bother with my previous comment. $z_{2i}$ corresponds to the power $g^{2i}$ so it corresponds to a quadratic residue modulo $p$ and $z_{2i-1}$ corresponds to non-residues and thus I can see that your sum $S$ is indeed the difference between two Gaussian periods I have mentioned in previous comment. I will have a deeper look at the computation of $S^2$.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Thanks for the complement. :)